# useState being reset with history.push

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

In my form I do the following

```js
import useReactRouter from 'use-react-router';

const { history } = useReactRouter();
onSubmit={async (values, { setSubmitting }) => {
  setSubmitting(true);
  fetch('/register', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(values),
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(async response => {
      setSubmitting(false);
      if (!response.success) return showAlert();
      await login();
      history.push('/profile');
    })
```

Login does this:

```js
export const AuthContext = createContext<any>(null);

const AuthProvider = ({ children }: ProviderProps): JSX.Element => {
  const [auth, setAuth] = useState({
    isAuthenticated: false,
    user: null
  });

  const login = () => {
    fetch('/me')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(response => {
        if (response) setAuth({ isAuthenticated: true, user: response });
      });
  };

  const logout = () => {
    fetch('/logout').then(() =>
      setAuth({ isAuthenticated: false, user: null })
    );
  };

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        state: {
          auth
        },
        actions: {
          login,
          logout
        }
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

After registering, `isAuthenticated returns true in the code below, but after navigating to another page it returns false again, what could be the problem?

```js
const PrivateRoute = (props: PrivateRouteProps) => {
  const { component: Component, ...rest } = props;

  const {
    state: {
      auth: { isAuthenticated }
    }
  } = useContext(AuthContext);

  console.log(isAuthenticated);
```

```js
<Router>
  <div>
    <AuthProvider>
      <Header />

      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={LocalizedUtils} locale={nlLocale}>
        <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
      </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
      <PrivateRoute exact path="/profile" component={Profile} />
    </AuthProvider>
  </div>
</Router>
```

I am looking for a solution to keep the isAuthenticated state after logging in through all the pages, even after clicking another link or after calling history.push

Comment: Could you provide the code in `AuthContext`? From the code available here, seems like you are not updating context when you update the state in `AuthProvider`. So when you try retrieving the `isAuthenticated` in `PrivateRoute`,  the state could be off.

Comment: I have added the code with AuthContext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason `isAuthenticated` returns `true` when you first land on the Profile page but reverts back to `false` when navigate to another page could only be that the `AuthProvider` component gets accidentally re-rendered when you click on a link and the state gets re-initialized.

Are you using the `<Link>` component for links? If not, when navigating to another page, the entire app will get re-rendered and the state does not persist.

Comment: Thanks, I did use href instead of Link in some places, but after logging in, I’m redirecting to the private route using history.push, after that, isAuthenticated is false already

Comment: @Daniell In the post you mentioned that "after registering, `isAuthenticated` returns true in the code below", which means `history.push` (the one in the `onSubmit` callback) was working correctly and did not trigger re-rendering. What was the case in which `history.push` didn't work?

Comment: For some reason it works now, fixed the href to Link components as well

Answer (score 0):

Your state is resetting because it's below Router in the hierarchy.

```
<AuthProvider>
<Router>
  <div>

      <Header />

      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={LocalizedUtils} locale={nlLocale}>
        <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
      </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
      <PrivateRoute exact path="/profile" component={Profile} />

  </div>
</Router>
</AuthProvider>
```

Comment: I just tested it again but I'm getting the same behaviour after making the changes

Comment: That is not why. You can absolutely put providers as a child of the Router. If you couldn't, none of the  child routes would be able to consume the route context that Router provides which is needed for the history API. The correct answer was mentioned by Claire Lin above @Daniell